# Silverstripe custom search

Tags: php, silverstripe, data-objects

I have a product catalog. There are:

Dzial.php - category page

```
 class Dzial extends Page {
    ...
        static $has_many = array(        
        'Marka' =>  'Marka'
    );
 function getCMSFields()  {
...
$gridField = new GridField("Marka", "marki:", $this->Marka(), $gridFieldConfig);
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Marki", $gridField);
```

PodDzial.php - subcategory page

```
class PodDzial extends Page {
.....
static $has_many = array(
    'Kategoria' =>  'Kategoria',
        'Produkt'   =>  'Produkt'
);
function getCMSFields() {
....
 $gridField = new GridField("Produkt", "Produkty:", $this->Produkt(), $gridFieldConfig);
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Produkty", $gridField);
  $gridField2 = new GridField("Kategoria", "Kategoria:", $this->Kategoria(), $gridFieldConfig);
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Kategorie", $gridField2);
```

Produkt.php - product - DataObjects which belong to PodDzial.php

```
class Produkt extends DataObject {
.....
static $has_one = array (
    'PodDzial'  =>  'PodDzial',
    'Marka' =>  'Marka',
    'Kategoria' =>  'Kategoria'
);
```

Kategoria.php - type of product- which belong to PodDzial (has_one) and to Produkt (has_many)

```
class Kategoria extends DataObject {
....
private static $has_one = array( 'PodDzial' =>  'PodDzial'  );    
private static $has_many = array ('Produkt' =>  'Produkt'  );
```

Marka.php - brand of product- which belong to Dzial (has_one) and to Produkt (has_many)

```
class Marka extends DataObject {
...
private static $has_one = array( 'Dzial'    =>  'Dzial'  ); 
private static $has_many = array ('Produkt' =>  'Produkt');
```

I work on custom search for Produkt's on PodDzial page.

The code which doesn't work properly:

```
class Produkt extends DataObject {
...
public function getDefaultSearchContext() {

    $fields = new FieldList(
        DropdownField::create(
            'MarkaID',
            'Marka',
            Marka::get()->map('ID','Title')
        )->setEmptyString('--Wybierz marke--') ,
        DropdownField::create(
            'KategoriaID',
            'Kategoria',
            Kategoria::get()->filter(array('PodDzialID' => $this->PodDzialID))->map('ID','Title')
        )->setEmptyString('--Wybierz kategorie--')
    );

    $filters = array(
        'MarkaID' => new ExactMatchFilter('MarkaID'),
        'KategoriaID' => new ExactMatchFilter('KategoriaID')
    );

    return new SearchContext(
        $this->class,
        $fields,
        $filters
    );
}
```

Both dropdown fields are working bad. They should list Kategoria's only  from its PodDzial holder and Marka's from parent Dzial.  Marka's field shows all Marka even from other categories now. Kategoria show nothing.

I use   those same dropdowns on fieldlist. Kategoria's work ok. It shows only data from given PodDzial. Markas are on parent holder (Dzial) and I cant access it there too :

```
class Produkt extends DataObject {
....
 $xxx = 'LEFT JOIN `SiteTree` ON `SiteTree`.ParentID=`Marka`.DzialID';  
    function getCMSFields(){
$fields = FieldList::create(

        TabSet::create("Root",

            Tab::create("Main",
              ....
DropdownField::create(
        'MarkaID',
        'Marka',
        Marka::get()->filter($xxx, array('DzialID' =>  'ParentID'))->map('ID','Title')
    )->setEmptyString('-- None --'),
    DropdownField::create(
        'KategoriaID',
        'Kategoria',
        Kategoria::get()->filter(array('PodDzialID' => $this->PodDzialID))->map('ID','Title')
    )->setEmptyString('-- None --')
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow I'd love to answer as you clearly have a question and have tried code to get there... however... it isn't clear what the goal is that you have... Is this in ModelAdmin?  The search filters there? If so what do you want the filters to do that they are not currently?

Comment: I corrected my question. I hope now is better to understand. I used gridfield on Dzial i Podzial page and Dropdown field for access this data on Produkt dataobject's page

Comment: You'd need something like https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-dependentdropdownfield/  for search, as you don't have a concrete Product Object with ID and relations when you create the search form. So you need some magic "field" or some ajax calls that search for Kategorias for the choosen Marka and so on.

Comment: There is no problem with search. I have additional text field and I put there page ID via jquery. Problem is thet there are at least 500 different podDzial pages with different Kategoria;s. I cant get page ID in simple way.